# ValueError: Setting an array element with a sequence - Imblearn

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, imblearn

I'm trying to do SMOTE oversampling from imblearn. This is my code:

```
X = data[['a','b','c']]
y = data['targets']

oversampler = SMOTE(random_state=42)

X_over, y_over = oversampler.fit_resample(X,y)
```

And, the last line `X_over, y_over = oversampler.fit_resample(X,y)`  raises the error  `setting an array elemenet with a sequence`

I am sure the reason is because of the shape of my 'X'.

X is a dataframe where each row of column 'a' is a list of length 118, each row of column 'b' a list of length 15 and column 'c' is an integer column.

i.e,

For example,

```
a(length - 118)                 b(length -15)                            c

[1,2,3,4,.....0]                [4,7,8,9...0]                            3
```

Now, how do I convert this dataframe X into array of shape (n_samples, n_features), which is required as per the [documentation](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html)

Could someone please help me transform the input dataframe to get rid of this error?

Comment: what do you mean by "each row of column 'a' is of type 'list' of length 118" ? is it a string or is it a list of floats?

Comment: A list of ints. I have edited my question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the columns, check that the lengths are the same first:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

data = pd.DataFrame({'targets':np.random.binomial(1,0.15,100),
'a':np.random.randint(0,10,(100,2)).tolist(), 
'b':np.random.randint(11,20,(100,3)).tolist(),
'c':np.random.randint(0,100,100)
})

data['a'].apply(len).value_counts()
2    100
```

Function to expand the columns, new columns will be named e.g a0..aN, and previous list columns will be dropped:

```
def expand_cols(da,col_list):
    for C in col_list:
        ix = [C+str(i) for i in range(len(da[C][0]))]
        da[ix] = pd.DataFrame(data[C].tolist(),columns = ix)
    
    da = da.drop(col_list,axis=1)
    return da
```

Your code, and we expand it when we fit:

```
X = data[['a','b','c']]
y = data['targets']

oversampler = SMOTE(random_state=42)

X_over, y_over = oversampler.fit_resample(expand_cols(X,['a','b']),y)
```

Looks like this:

```
X_over.head()

    c  a0  a1  b0  b1  b2
0  67   4   0  19  15  16
1  12   3   7  12  17  19
2  41   8   9  15  18  18
3  35   8   0  11  13  11
4  46   0   5  12  12  12
```